# How to create a Ruby module in Java using JRuby?

Tags: java, ruby, module, jruby

In Ruby, I can have a module like:

```
module Greeter
  def greet
    print "Hello"
  end
end
```

And my class can get the `greet` method like this:

```
class MyClass
  include Greeter
end

obj = MyClass.new
obj.greet
```

Now, I would like to have my module `Greeter` implemented in Java instead. I'm using JRuby. I'm unsure about how to create a Ruby module in Java (in such a way that I can do `include` normally).

For a moment I though of making a Java interface. Including it in my Ruby class doesn't throw errors, but it really isn't the same thing since modules seem to implement the methods, whereas a Java interface doesn't.

Comment: Um... *why*? How is this going to help? I think it'd obfuscate what your code is doing, and not in a good way.

Comment: In jruby I commonly find myself pushing ruby code down into java implementations for performance reasons.

Comment: @theTinMan: Mostly curiosity. Frankly though, hiding such module wouldn't be so bad for me. I'm writing a game development framework and honestly, the end-user definitely doesn't want to mess around with this module - they only need (and should) include it in their Ruby classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how would implement exactly the same code you have above using a Java extension.

Everything here is at the default package level (no package), if you would like to have packages just change the module name.

First, create the Greeter class:

```
import org.jruby.anno.JRubyMethod;
import org.jruby.runtime.ThreadContext;
import org.jruby.runtime.builtin.IRubyObject;

public class Greeter {

    @JRubyMethod
    public static void greet( ThreadContext context, IRubyObject self ) {
        System.out.printf("Hello from %s%n", self);
    }

}
```

Then you need the GreeterService to load it:

```
import org.jruby.Ruby;
import org.jruby.RubyModule;
import org.jruby.runtime.load.BasicLibraryService;

import java.io.IOException;

public class GreeterService implements BasicLibraryService {

    @Override
    public boolean basicLoad(final Ruby runtime) throws IOException {
        RubyModule greeter = runtime.defineModule(Greeter.class.getSimpleName());
        greeter.defineAnnotatedMethods(Greeter.class);

        return true;
    }

}
```

And with these classes defined, here's how you can use them in a JRuby script:

```
require 'target/jruby-example.jar'
require 'greeter'

class MyClass
  include Greeter
end

obj = MyClass.new
obj.greet
```

The `jruby-example.jar` contains both classes above compiled and packaged. There isn't much else to be done here, now you have your module that you can include anywhere. For a bigger example, just check how the [Enumerable](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/jruby/RubyEnumerable.java) module is implemented.